# How to append a new line to a file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a code that asks for a user name and saves it in a text file. The problem is when I close the console app and try to run it again, it deletes all the information that was in the text file. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

```
public static void UserWriter(StreamWriter WriteNewLine)
{
    bool EndOfWrite = true;
    char Answer;
    while (EndOfWrite)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("eneter a user name");
        WriteNewLine.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("did you finish ? Y/N");
        Wrong: Answer = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (Answer)
        {
            case 'Y':
                EndOfWrite = false;
                break;
            case 'N':
                break;
            default:
                goto Wrong;
         }
     }
     WriteNewLine.Close();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fileLoction = @"C:\project\user.txt";
    StreamWriter WriteNewLine = new StreamWriter(fileLoction);
    if (File.Exists(fileLoction))
    {
        WriteNewLine.Close();
        WriteNewLine = File.AppendText(fileLoction);
        UserWriter(WriteNewLine);
        WriteNewLine.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        UserWriter(WriteNewLine);
        WriteNewLine.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Along with @metal answer, this shall do the job.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fileLoction = @"C:\project\user.txt";
    StreamWriter WriteNewLine = new StreamWriter(fileLoction, true);
    WriteNewLine = File.AppendText(fileLoction);
    WriteNewLine.Close();
}
```